Gene sequence retrieval (NCBI gene or ENSEMBLE)
I wanted to retrieve the sequence for MPL gene (exon 10). NCBI gene showed 12 exons for the gene and ENSEMBLE showed only 4 exons. The literature mentions that the pathognomonic mutations in MPL gene (MPL S505, MPL W515) are found in exon 10. I am able to retrieve the exon 10 sequence from NCBI gene, for which I need to design primers. However, the ENSEMBLE DB displays only 4 exons

Which database needs to be used for sequence retrieval if I need to design sequencing primers ?
Are the sequences for genes and other parameters different in both DBs (NCBI and ENSEMBLE) ?
Is MANE (Minimal Annotation of Nucleotide Sequences) useful ?


I'd consider https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com if there is no response here.

......
